# Change form value= attribute with Javascript

Tags: javascript, input

I need a simple javascript that will change the value= attribute to 2 when the page is loaded.

```
<input type="number" step="1" min="1" name="quantity" value="1" title="Qty" class="input-text qty text">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
addEventListener('load', function() {
    document.getElementsByClassName('qty')[0].value = 2;
});
```

1. You first add an event listener to the `load` event, so that it runs after the page's loaded
2. Within the event listener's callback function, you select the element. In this script, I select for the class `qty`, since that class seemed like it was the most specific of the three. You should add an `id` attribute to the input to most accurately select it though.
3. You get the first result, at index `[0]`, and set its value to 2.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName - using "input-text qty text" selects against *any* of the listed class names; it broadens the scope (OR), not restricts (AND).

Comment: @user2864740 oh... Well I don't usually use classes to select anyway, but I'll change my answer. Thanks!